# Gruntjs makes files disappear

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs

So I am making angularjs project using grunt, bower and yeoman.  In development everything goes great but when I try to build the project grunt decides that one of the bower components needs to disappear from the sources list at index.html.  So basically I have the following list:

```
<script src="bower_components/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/sass-bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
```

And after I start the building process the last line with angular-animate disappears and so the entire application fails because ngAnimate can't be loaded.

> Why does Grunt hate ngAnimate so much and what am I to do to make it
>   like it so it won't throw it down the trash?

Here's my Gruntfile if it can offer any sense to this.

```
> // Generated on 2014-02-21 using generator-angular 0.7.1 'use strict';
> 
> // # Globbing // for performance reasons we're only matching one level
> down: // 'test/spec/{,*/}*.js' // use this if you want to recursively
> match all subfolders: // 'test/spec/**/*.js'
> 
> module.exports = function (grunt) {
> 
>   // Load grunt tasks automatically  
> require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);
> 
>   // Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times  
> require('time-grunt')(grunt);
> 
>   // Define the configuration for all the tasks   grunt.initConfig({
> 
>     // Project settings
>     yeoman: {
>       // configurable paths
>       app: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'app',
>       dist: 'dist'
>     },
> 
>     // Watches files for changes and runs tasks based on the changed files
>     watch: {
>       js: {
>         files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'],
>         tasks: ['newer:jshint:all'],
>         options: {
>           livereload: true
>         }
>       },
>       jsTest: {
>         files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js'],
>         tasks: ['newer:jshint:test', 'karma']
>       },
>       compass: {
>         files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
>         tasks: ['compass:server', 'autoprefixer']
>       },
>       gruntfile: {
>         files: ['Gruntfile.js']
>       },
>       livereload: {
>         options: {
>           livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
>         },
>         files: [
>           '<%= yeoman.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
>           '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
>           '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
>         ]
>       }
>     },
> 
>     // The actual grunt server settings
>     connect: {
>       options: {
>         port: 9000,
>         // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
>         hostname: 'localhost',
>         livereload: 35729
>       },
>       livereload: {
>         options: {
>           open: true,
>           base: [
>             '.tmp',
>             '<%= yeoman.app %>'
>           ]
>         }
>       },
>       test: {
>         options: {
>           port: 9001,
>           base: [
>             '.tmp',
>             'test',
>             '<%= yeoman.app %>'
>           ]
>         }
>       },
>       dist: {
>         options: {
>           base: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
>         }
>       }
>     },
> 
>     // Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
>     jshint: {
>       options: {
>         jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
>         reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
>       },
>       all: [
>         'Gruntfile.js',
>         '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
>       ],
>       test: {
>         options: {
>           jshintrc: 'test/.jshintrc'
>         },
>         src: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js']
>       }
>     },
> 
>     // Empties folders to start fresh
>     clean: {
>       dist: {
>         files: [{
>           dot: true,
>           src: [
>             '.tmp',
>             '<%= yeoman.dist %>/*',
>             '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git*'
>           ]
>         }]
>       },
>       server: '.tmp'
>     },
> 
>     // Add vendor prefixed styles
>     autoprefixer: {
>       options: {
>         browsers: ['last 1 version']
>       },
>       dist: {
>         files: [{
>           expand: true,
>           cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
>           src: '{,*/}*.css',
>           dest: '.tmp/styles/'
>         }]
>       }
>     },
> 
>     // Automatically inject Bower components into the app
>     'bower-install': {
>       app: {
>         html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
>         ignorePath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/'
>       }
>     },
> 
> 
> 
> 
>     // Compiles Sass to CSS and generates necessary files if requested
>     compass: {
>       options: {
>         sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
>         cssDir: '.tmp/styles',
>         generatedImagesDir: '.tmp/images/generated',
>         imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
>         javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
>         fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/fonts',
>         importPath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components',
>         httpImagesPath: '/images',
>         httpGeneratedImagesPath: '/images/generated',
>         httpFontsPath: '/styles/fonts',
>         relativeAssets: false,
>         assetCacheBuster: false,
>         raw: 'Sass::Script::Number.precision = 10\n'
>       },
>       dist: {
>         options: {
>           generatedImagesDir: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/generated'
>         }
>       },
>       server: {
>         options: {
>           debugInfo: true
>         }
>       }
>     },
> 
>     // Renames files for browser caching purposes
>     rev: {
>       dist: {
>         files: {
>           src: [
>             '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
>             '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
>             '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
>             '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/*'
>           ]
>         }
>       }
>     },
> 
>     // Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
>     // concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
>     // additional tasks can operate on them
>     useminPrepare: {
>       html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
>       options: {
>         dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
>       }
>     },
> 
>     // Performs rewrites based on rev and the useminPrepare configuration
>     usemin: {
>       html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
>       css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
>       options: {
>         assetsDirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>']
>       }
>     },
> 
>     // The following *-min tasks produce minified files in the dist folder
>     imagemin: {
>       dist: {
>         files: [{
>           expand: true,
>           cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
>           src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}',
>           dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
>         }]
>       }
>     },
>     svgmin: {
>       dist: {
>         files: [{
>           expand: true,
>           cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
>           src: '{,*/}*.svg',
>           dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
>         }]
>       }
>     },
>     htmlmin: {
>       dist: {
>         options: {
>           collapseWhitespace: true,
>           collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
>           removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
>           removeOptionalTags: true
>         },
>         files: [{
>           expand: true,
>           cwd: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
>           src: ['*.html', 'views/{,*/}*.html'],
>           dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
>         }]
>       }
>     },
> 
>     // Allow the use of non-minsafe AngularJS files. Automatically makes it
>     // minsafe compatible so Uglify does not destroy the ng references
>     ngmin: {
>       dist: {
>         files: [{
>           expand: true,
>           cwd: '.tmp/concat/scripts',
>           src: '*.js',
>           dest: '.tmp/concat/scripts'
>         }]
>       }
>     },
> 
>     // Replace Google CDN references
>     cdnify: {
>       dist: {
>         html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/*.html']
>       }
>     },
> 
>     // Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
>     copy: {
>       dist: {
>         files: [{
>           expand: true,
>           dot: true,
>           cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
>           dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
>           src: [
>             '*.{ico,png,txt}',
>             '.htaccess',
>             '*.html',
>             'views/{,*/}*.html',
>             'bower_components/**/*',
>             'images/{,*/}*.{webp}',
>             'fonts/*'
>           ]
>         }, {
>           expand: true,
>           cwd: '.tmp/images',
>           dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
>           src: ['generated/*']
>         }]
>       },
>       styles: {
>         expand: true,
>         cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
>         dest: '.tmp/styles/',
>         src: '{,*/}*.css'
>       }
>     },
> 
>     // Run some tasks in parallel to speed up the build process
>     concurrent: {
>       server: [
>         'compass:server'
>       ],
>       test: [
>         'compass'
>       ],
>       dist: [
>         'compass:dist',
>         'imagemin',
>         'svgmin'
>       ]
>     },
> 
>     // By default, your `index.html`'s <!-- Usemin block --> will take care of
>     // minification. These next options are pre-configured if you do not wish
>     // to use the Usemin blocks.
>     // cssmin: {
>     //   dist: {
>     //     files: {
>     //       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
>     //         '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
>     //         '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'
>     //       ]
>     //     }
>     //   }
>     // },
>     // uglify: {
>     //   dist: {
>     //     files: {
>     //       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
>     //         '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js'
>     //       ]
>     //     }
>     //   }
>     // },
>     // concat: {
>     //   dist: {}
>     // },
> 
>     // Test settings
>     karma: {
>       unit: {
>         configFile: 'karma.conf.js',
>         singleRun: true
>       }
>     }   });
> 
> 
>   grunt.registerTask('serve', function (target) {
>     if (target === 'dist') {
>       return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
>     }
> 
>     grunt.task.run([
>       'clean:server',
>       'bower-install',
>       'concurrent:server',
>       'autoprefixer',
>       'connect:livereload',
>       'watch'
>     ]);   });
> 
>   grunt.registerTask('server', function () {
>     grunt.log.warn('The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.');
>     grunt.task.run(['serve']);   });
> 
>   grunt.registerTask('test', [
>     'clean:server',
>     'concurrent:test',
>     'autoprefixer',
>     'connect:test',
>     'karma'   ]);
> 
>   grunt.registerTask('build', [
>     'clean:dist',
>     'bower-install',
>     'useminPrepare',
>     'concurrent:dist',
>     'autoprefixer',
>     'concat',
>     'ngmin',
>     'copy:dist',
>     'cdnify',
>     'cssmin',
>     'uglify',
>     'rev',
>     'usemin',
>     'htmlmin'   ]);
> 
>   grunt.registerTask('default', [
>     'newer:jshint',
>     // 'test',
>     'build'   ]); };
```

Comment: how does your bower.json looks like?

Comment: @michael Oh snap so that was it... and here I thought bower install would add that line automatically.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bower can modify the `bower.json` file on install if the `-S` or `--save` option is used. This will put the needed reference in the `bower.json` file.